# How to retrieve a db from Assets folder Xamarin

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have created my database class with all the methods I need following MS Doc at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases) with the exception I have multiple database, but this is not my current problem, for the moment I have just selected the first one in the list by doing this in **constants.cs**:

```
public static string DatabasePath
    {
        get
        {
            var basePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
            return Path.Combine(basePath, DatabaseNames[0]); //DA SISTEMARE !!!
        }
    }
```

Right now my DB files are stored in the `Asset folder` (Android) and `Resources folder` (iOS) as **AndroidAsset** and **BundleResource** with the option `copy always` checked.

Now I was wondering how am I supposed to move / copy these files in the `Personal folder` so I can read and use them.

I've seen some other answers and xamarin forum posts but they are either old or not explained really well..

By the way I was looking for a solution that will work for both Android and iOS.

Comment: use AssetManager to read it, then System.IO to write it to a writable folder.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-assets?tabs=windows

Comment: @Jason what about iOS? thanks for your comment btw

Comment: iOS does not have Assets.  You can just include a file in the project root as content, then read it using normal File.IO and write to a writable path